# fetching salesforce object's record count using java

Tags: java, web-services

I have a Java code using **partner API** for connecting to Salesforce.

I am trying to get the number of records/rows for my salesforce object. All my tries were unsuccessful.

I went through  a sample code that uses **AggregateResult** class for this purpose.When I try to implement it, the program throws error(`Cannot cast from SObject to AggregateResult`).

How can I do it.

Comment: If you post sample code we might be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

The following may work for you.  In my system I have an object Device that is a child of Account.  There is also an object Alert that is a child of Device.  I used an aggregate query to get the account ids for Alert records that meet a certain condtion.

```
StringBuilder openAlertQuery = new StringBuilder();
openAlertQuery.append("SELECT Device__r.Account__c");
openAlertQuery.append(" FROM Alert__c WHERE Cleared__c = FALSE GROUP BY Device__r.Account__c");
List<SObject> alertRecords = sfdcServer.doQuery(openAlertQuery.toString());
List<String> accountIds = new ArrayList<String>();
for (SObject alert : alertRecords)
{
    String accountId = (String) alert.getChild("Account__c").getValue();
    accountIds.add(accountId);
}
```

Notice the SObject method is getChild(name) rather than the usual getField(name).    getChild(name) returns an com.sforce.ws.bind.XmlObject which has the getValue() method.